# Creating a custom search to produce contributions as results

Tags: contributions, custom-search

I've followed the [documentation](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Custom-Search+Extension) to create a custom search and I find this capability to be quite powerful for finding and displaying information about contacts.

Now I would like to create a custom search to show a specific set of *contributions* and then (most importantly) allow me to perform actions on those specific contributions (e.g. "export contributions", "send thank-you letters").

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Yeah, custom searches for contribs work mostly the same way (from memory - think you just copy a different file to get you started), ditto the doing things known as "search tasks" - I added a search task that duplicates selected payments with today's date (assists with entering payments given regularly).

Comment: You may be interested by this post :
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25078/smart-group-features-extension-to-memberships-events-contributions-activities

Answer (score 5):

Start with the code for Find Contributions (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Contribute/Form/SearchContribution.php) and customize it as necessary to get the results you want, eg by hardcoding some values.

Next, choose a task similar to what you want to do from the list at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/tree/master/CRM/Contribute/Form/Task, and copy and modify it as necessary. Next, after reviewing  https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Contribute/Task.php, find a hook like buildForm to modify the search form so it includes your new task(s).