# Could an extension add fields to the standard Find Contributions form?

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, payment-processor, search, custom-search

A client would like to search for contributions by payment processor. The built-in search forms don't include a payment processor field, although the data exists within the Civi database.

As [the answer to another question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/31/446) describes, I could create a custom search based on the basic Find Contributions form. I could then replace the default Find Contributions menu item with my new improved version.

But, hypothetically, could I instead use an extension to insert a field for payment processor into the basic Find Contributions form itself, along with some code to create the SQL query? Is such an approach possible and advisable?

Answer (score 1):

How about building an extension that creates custom report - where contributions can be e.g. filtered by or grouped by Payment Processor id? Much easier to create that and likely more useful too.

Comment: Hi Karin, thanks, that may be what I end up doing. But, just for the purpose of understanding Civi's limitations, I'm still looking for an answer to the question: could an extension modify the basic Find Contributions form itself?

Comment: Yes - it could; but I think Reports are way easier - esp. when you're getting started w/ Extensions!